# Any 3rd party tools that integrate IIS management with some sort of application inventory/change management process?

Tags: iis

I've got an environment with several IIS 6 web servers hosting hundreds of apps (dozens of sites, hundreds of virtual directories) all with a myriad of different configurations belonging to dozens of different developers (all deploying apps willy nilly).

Is there some sort of managed software solution that will

- centralize management of all my IIS6 environments
- provide some inventory functionality
- allow for reporting or querying of said application inventory
- enforce and automate some sort of deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a complete answer for you, but based on other threads here at SF, I have seen MS [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/expand/WebDeploy) as a very good building block for it. I'm going to start playing with it, as soon as I ask the infrastructure team to deploy the agent to our test IIS servers.